Issues getting a console start with specific environment / needs spyder-kernels=3.0
Here's my current configuration:

macOS w/ Apple M1 Pro on Sonomar 14.6.1
Spyder 6.0.1
conda environment (EnvTest) running python 3.8.19

I am trying to start a new console for a specific conda environment (e.g. EnvTest which runs pythong 3.8.19). While in Spyder, I go to Menu > consoles > new console in environment > conda EnvTest. Spyder tries to boot up the console but generates the following error message.
The Python environment or installation whose interpreter is located at /opt/anaconda3/envs/XCS221/bin/
python doesn't have spyder‑kernels version >=3.0.0,<3.1.0 installed.

Without this module and specific version is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you.

You can install it by activating your environment (if necessary) and then running in a system terminal: conda install spyder-kernels=3.0

I have activated EnvTest in a terminal by executing conda activate EnvTest. I then run conda install spyder-kernels=3.0 but get an error message as follow:
Could not solve for environment specs The following packages are incompatible 
└─ spyder-kernels 3.0**  is not installable because there are no viable options
    ├─ spyder-kernels 3.0.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
    └─ spyder-kernels 3.0.0 would require
       └─ __win, which is missing on the system.

So, I am a bit stuck. I search a bit and actually couldn't find any evidence of spyder-kernels beyond 2.5 (or something like that). What am I missing?
Thanks for any help you might be able to provide!
